# Java: How to check if chars are contained in a string

Tags: java, string, character

Evening,

I'm trying to find the best solution to solve this problem:

**Input:**

```
String1 = "algrtvy";
String2 = "alg";
String3 = "gvy";
String4 = "mgr";
String5 = "aall";
```

Are the chars of str2, 3 , 4, 5 contained in 1?

**Output**

```
true 
true 
false
false
```

so, i'm not checking for the sequence (substring) but for the single characters.

Any tips?
I'm looking for the fasted solution in computational time.

**Solution:**

This solution is an implemented version from the @davidxxx's answer.

```
public boolean haveChars(String longerString, String shorterString) {
    String chars = longerString;
    for (char c : shorterString.toCharArray()){
        int index = chars.indexOf(c);
        if (index == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            chars = chars.substring(0,index) + chars.substring(index + 1);
        }      
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate as OP doesn't require to check for substring. OP checks for subsequence.

Comment: The problem statement is misleading. "Contained in" suggests substring, but the `true` output for `String3` suggests it's concerned with individual characters.

Comment: it is not a duplicate @EnzoNocera, I am not looking for a substring, I'm looking for characters checking.

Comment: @jsheeran exactly, I'm not looking for a substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Store in an `int` value the number of characters to find in the input.
It is the counter that will allow to know if the match is successful.

And also make a copy of the current model to match.
It is not mandatory as `String` are immutable but it makes things clearer.

2) Iterate on each character contained in the input that you try to match with your model copy.

3) As soon a character matches, decrement the counter and remove it from the model copy.

4) As soon as the counter is valued to `0`, it means that the input and the model match.

5) If after the loop of the characters of the input, the counter is not valued to `0`, it means that the input and the model doesn't match.

You could have a method like that :

```
public static boolean isMatch(String model, String input) {

    int nbCharacterRemaningToFind = input.length();
    String copyModel = model;

    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        String cInString = String.valueOf(c);

        if (copyModel.contains(cInString)) {
            copyModel = copyModel.replaceFirst(cInString, "");
            nbCharacterRemaningToFind--;
            if (nbCharacterRemaningToFind == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: for the moment this is the best solution because it considers the double characters. But is O(n^2)... And I'm starting guessing that is not possible to go lower.

Comment: error: empty character literal
     remainingCharacters = remainingCharacters.replace(c, '');

Comment: Indeed. I have written the code without checking its compilation. Sorry. `Character.MIN_VALUE` should be used for empty char. I have edited to propose a simpler solution.

Comment: edited the question with a solution from you answer. I just did some changes to get a best computational time in the medium case.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is short, you can just use

```
String string = "abcdefgh";
String sub = "adf";

boolean ok = sub.chars().allMatch(c -> string.indexOf((char) c) >= 0);
```

If M is the size of string, and N is the size of sub, it's O(N * M) in the worst case.

If it's large, or if you want to do apply the check on the same string multiple times, you can start by making it a Set, and use the same principle:

```
Set<Character> set = string.chars().mapToObj(c -> ((char) c)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
ok = sub.chars().allMatch(c -> set.contains((char) c));
```

This is O(M) + O(N).

Another possibility is to instead make a set out of the sub string:

```
Set<Character> subset = sub.chars().mapToObj(c -> ((char) c)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
for (int i = 0; i < string.length() && !subset.isEmpty(); i++) {
    subset.remove(string.charAt(i));
}
ok = subset.isEmpty();
```

Again O(M) + O(N).

You should now measure on your expected inputs. But beware: benchmarks in Java are hard.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I'm trying to avoid other data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check create a new function (containsEachChar) that checks the contains like this:`

```
public boolean containsEachChar(String string1, String string2) {
       for (char c : string2.toCharArray()) {
            if(string1.indexOf( c) == -1){
               return false;
            }
       }
       return true;
}
`
```

The statement string1.indexOf(c) returns the position of the 'c' in 'string1'. In case 'c' is not present in 'string1', -1 is returned.

Now, you can call above method from your main method:`

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string1 = "algrtvy";
        String string2 = "alg";
        String string3 = "gvy";
        String string4 = "mgr";
        System.out.println(containsEachChar(string1, string2));
        System.out.println(containsEachChar(string1, string3));
        System.out.println(containsEachChar(string1, string4));
    }
```

Output:
true
true
false

What the code in containsEachChar does is that,

1. It iterates the characters in string2.
2. As it is not essential to check further chars in string2 if the value string1.indexOf(c) is -1, the function simply returns false.

Answer (score 0):

**Note this is probably an inefficient solution, but what i'm trying to do here is make use of containsALL which checks if content of a collections is contained within another collections**

String string1 = "algrtvy";

```
    //turn it to arraylist
    List<String> string1ArrayList = Arrays.asList(string1.split(""));
    String string2 = "alg";
    String string3 = "gvy";
    String string4 = "mgr";
    String string5 = "aall";

    //check its in the arraylist
    System.out.println(string1ArrayList.containsAll(Arrays.asList(string2.split(""))));
    System.out.println(string1ArrayList.containsAll(Arrays.asList(string3.split(""))));
    System.out.println(string1ArrayList.containsAll(Arrays.asList(string4.split(""))));
    System.out.println(string1ArrayList.containsAll(Arrays.asList(string5.split(""))));
```

*

> results: true true false true

*

Comment: well you answer is incorrect, the results should be: true true false false, but thank you!

Comment: are duplicates not allowed e.g. aa should only match one a? in the case of  "aall"